# Async call from synchronous method

Tags: c#, caching, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async cache that is suppose to block threads asynchronously that enter an "AsyncLock" with the same cache key (while that key is being updated). I'm wondering if since the caller of the async method is not async will other threads requesting the same cache key block asynchronously or synchronously? In other words will the waiting threads be returned to the thread pool while awaiting the result or will they just be uselessly blocked until the result is returned and that AsyncLock/key is open?

Here is some code snippets below showing all of the context of my question. If you need more of the code see here https://github.com/stewie1570/Cache for the full & very small public GitHub repo.

Here is synchronouse method calling the async code:

```
    public T Get(string key, Func<T> func, int entryLifeTimeInSeconds = 60)
    {
        T ret = null;
        _lock.Run(key, () => ret = PerformNonThreadSafeCache(key, func, entryLifeTimeInSeconds));
        return ret;
    }
```

Here is what it calls:

```
    public async void Run(string key, Action action)
    {
        using (var releaser = await _locks.GetOrAdd(key, s => new AsyncLock()).LockAsync())
        {
            action();
        }
    }
```

And here is AsyncLock.LockAsync()

```
    public Task<IDisposable> LockAsync()
    {
        var wait = _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        return wait.IsCompleted ? _releaser :
                    wait.ContinueWith((t, o) => (IDisposable)o,
                    _releaser.Result,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                    TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

All of the other threads and articles I've read either show a similar situation (but not close enough to this for me to tell if this is correct or not) or a situation where basically the entire call stack is async which lead me to this concern & question.

Comment: Never write `async void` methods.  And, yes, any method that calls an async method must itself be async if you care about the result.

Comment: So in this implementation is it useless to have an "AsyncLock" vs. a regular lock?

Comment: It's worse than useless; it's completely broken.  If you want async, _everything_ must be async.

Comment: That, in a nutshell is exactly was what I was wondering. So if there is any async code all of it must be async to see the benefits of async..right?

Comment: Or to let me rephrase - if any of the call stack is async, then all of it should be...

Comment: @StewartAnderson, yes indeed: ["Async All the Way"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: FYI, to anyone that visits the GitHub repo - it has been updated to reflect the above information. So the snippets will no longer reflect the repo. Also, if you notice another issue with the repo especially with how I'm using async/await please let me know here in this thread so others may benifit - but please be gentle. I'm still pretty green to async usage.